# Can I enroll in the iOS developer program with a brazilian account?

Tags: ios, iphone

If so, do the apps that I release go exclusively to the brazilian app store or do they go to the american one, too?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enrol in the developer program with any Apple ID account, regardless of country of origin. With this, you have the option to sell your application anywhere where the App Store is available; you're not restricted to the country of origin for the Apple ID.